# Dynamic Text Boxes in Dialogue Window in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, dialog

I'm new to apps script and javascript so this may be a really basic question but I can't seem to find an answer to this issue anywhere.

I would like to have a dynamic dialogue box based on cell values in a certain field.

Here's my code so far.

```js
 

   function showPrompt() {
  var L,sourceSheet,ss,targetSh;

  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  targetSh = ss.getSheetByName('Stop Time Generator');
  sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('My Shift Log');

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.
  var values = targetSh.getRange('I2:I').getValues()

  L = values.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < L; i++){
    if(values[i]!=""){
    var result = ui.prompt(
      'Please Log waste weight for: '  + values[i],
        ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

    // Process the user's response.
    var button = result.getSelectedButton();
    var text = result.getResponseText();
    Logger.log('text: ' + text)

    if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
      targetSh.getRange(i+2,10).setValue(text)
      sourceSheet.getRange('d10').copyTo(targetSh.getRange('T1') , {contentsOnly:true});
      if (!text) {
        ui.alert('Please enter a number value or click CANCEL');
      }
    } else if (button == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
      // User clicked "Cancel".
      ui.alert('Your response wasn\'t recorded');
      break;
    } else if (button == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
      // User clicked X in the title bar.
      ui.alert('Your response wasn\'t recorded');
    }
   }
 }
}
```

I'm trying to have the dialog box pop up asking for the weight of the value in cell I2 first, then once submitted, the weight of the value in I3 etc.

So far it just pops up on a loop with a 0 above the text field

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

If there's a similar problem that I haven't found, please link me to it.

Thanks,

Comment: Change: `'Please Log waste weight for'&values[i],` to: `'Please Log waste weight for: ' + values[i],`  The plus sign must be used to concatenate text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
function showPrompt() {
  var L,sourceSheet,ss,targetSh;

  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  targetSh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet3');
  sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('My Shift Log');

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.
  var values = ss.getSheetByName('Stop Time Generator').getRange('I2:I').getValues()

  L = values.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < L; i++){

    var result = ui.prompt(
      'Please Log waste weight for: '  + values[i],
        ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

    // Process the user's response.
    var button = result.getSelectedButton();
    var text = result.getResponseText();
    Logger.log('text: ' + text)

    if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
      targetSh.getRange('Q1').setValue(text)
      sourceSheet.getRange('d10').copyTo(targetSh.getRange('T1') , {contentsOnly:true});
      if (!text) {
        ui.alert('Please enter a value or click CANCEL');
      }
    } else if (button == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
      // User clicked "Cancel".
      ui.alert('Your response wasn\'t recorded');
      break;
    } else if (button == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
      // User clicked X in the title bar.
      ui.alert('Your response wasn\'t recorded');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This works except it also loops through values that are blank in the range I2:I

Comment: I added an if statement to filter those blanks out. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.